# Поиск в базе данных Spring MVC и JPA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

Только осваиваю Spring и, вот такая задача - нужно осуществить поиск по разным параметрам. Причем параметры все не обязательные, т.е. могут присутствовать как несколько параметров сразу, так и только один из них. Опыта со Спрингом мало, поэтому, где ошибаюсь не знаю, но поиск не происходит.
Есть html-форма:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title th:text="${title}">Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity ="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/styles.css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}">
</head>
<body onload="checkFindFields();">
<div id="header_container">
<h1 class="header_content centered">Find Client</h1>
</div>
<div style="width: 300px; margin: 0 auto">
<form id="find_form" method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/clients/find}" th:object="${client}">
    <p class="centered" style="width: 300px; margin: 20px">Find Client</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">ID: </td>
            <td>
                <label for="id"></label>
                <input class="auth" style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="id" id="id" th:fileld="*{id}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">Name: </td>
            <td>
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input class="auth" style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="name" id="name" th:field="*{firstName}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">Surname: </td>
            <td>
                <label for="surname"></label>
                <input class="auth" style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="surname" id="surname" th:field="*{lastName}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">Email: </td>
            <td>
                <label for="email"></label>
                <input class="auth" style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">Balance: </td>
            <td>
                <label for="balance"></label>
                <input class="auth" style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="balance" id="balance" th:field="*{balance}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">Phones: </td>
            <td>
                <label for="phones"></label>
                <input class="auth" style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="phones" id="phones"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px">Identity: </td>
            <td>
                <label for="identity"></label>
                <input class="auth" style="margin: 5px" type="text" name="identity" id="identity"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="margin: 10px">
        <tr>
            <td><input style="width: 110px" type="submit" value="Find"/></td>
            <td style="width: 80px"></td>
            <td><input style="width: 110px" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="openPage('/Client')"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../static/js/main.js" th:src="@{/js/main.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Создал пользовательский интерфейс ClientRepositoryCustom:

```
public interface ClientRepositoryCustom {
List<Client> findAnyClient(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Double balance);}
```

Далее, класс, имплементирующий этот интерфейс:

```
@Repository
public class ClientRepositoryCustomImpl implements ClientRepositoryCustom {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public ClientRepositoryCustomImpl() {
}

@Override
public List<Client> findAnyClient(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Double balance) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Client> cq = cb.createQuery(Client.class);

    Root<Client> clientRoot = cq.from(Client.class);
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if (id != null){
        predicates.add(cb.equal(clientRoot.get("id"), id));
    }
    if (firstName != null){
        predicates.add(cb.like(clientRoot.get("firstName"), firstName));
    }
    if (lastName != null){
        predicates.add(cb.like(clientRoot.get("lastName"), lastName));
    }
    if (email != null){
        predicates.add(cb.like(clientRoot.get("email"), email));
    }
    if (balance != null){
        predicates.add(cb.equal(clientRoot.get("balance"), balance));
    }
    cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

    return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}}
```

И, фрагмент контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class ClientController {

@Autowired
private ClientService clientService;

@Autowired
private ClientRepositoryCustomImpl clientRepositoryCustom;


@RequestMapping(value = "/clients/find", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getFindFormCommand(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("title", "Find Client");
    model.addAttribute("client", new Client());
    return "FindFormView";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/clients/find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String findClient(@ModelAttribute Client client, Model model,
                         @RequestParam(value = "id") Long id,
                         @RequestParam(value = "firstName") String firstName,
                         @RequestParam(value = "lastName") String lastName,
                         @RequestParam(value = "email") String email,
                         @RequestParam(value = "balance") Double balance){
    model.addAttribute("title", "Find Client");

    List<Client> clientList = clientRepositoryCustom.findAnyClient(id, firstName, lastName, email, balance);
    model.addAttribute("clientList", clientList);

    return "ViewCommand";
}}
```

Укажите, что делаю не так? Где ошибки, - почему не работает поиск?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использую Spring Data Jpa.

```
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ClientRepositoryCustom extends JpaRepository<Client, Long> {

    List<Client> findAllByIdOrFirstNameOrLastNameOrEmailOrBalance(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Double balance);
}
```

Использую это все так:

```
@Autowired
private ClientRepositoryCustom clientRepository;
```

Где-то в методе:

```
clientRepository.findAllByIdOrFirstNameOrLastNameOrEmailOrBalance(params...);
```

Comment: Похоже вы правы. Не надо усложнять. Один метод, который ищет по любым параметрам и все. Спасибо!